# Collapse a string over a moving average window

Tags: r

I am calculating the moving average of a vector over a window of 3 months. I'd like to add another column to the data frame below that collapses months in the window. So in the example below:

```
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12), x = rnorm(12))

df$month <- month(df$Date, abbr = TRUE, label = TRUE)

df$moving_x <- as.numeric(stats::filter(df$x,rep(1/3,3), sides=2))
```

Now for `df[2,]`, I get the following:

```
> df[2,]
        Date          x month     moving_x
2 2000-02-01 0.07902587   Feb -0.008438176
```

What I would like to get is

```
> df[2,]
        Date          x month     moving_x month_window
2 2000-02-01 0.07902587   Feb -0.008438176 Jan-Feb-Mar
```

So my question is, can anyone recommend a good way to create `month_window` i.e. the range over which the moving average is calculated? I'd prefer a solution that use only base R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an only base R solution you could use `sapply`:

```
df$window <- sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x) paste(df$month[x-1],
                                            df$month[x],
                                            df$month[x+1],sep="-"))
```

You can `ifelse` the function for invalid locations if you don't like the behavior at the start and end

Answer (score 3):

Here are some solutions:

**1) rollapply** Use `rollapply` and associated routines on `x` and `month` like this:

```
library(zoo)

transform(df, moving_x = rollmean(x, 3, fill = NA), 
   month_window = rollapply(month, 3, paste, collapse = "-", fill = NA))
```

giving:

```
         Date           x month   moving_x month_window
1  2000-01-01  0.37963948   Jan         NA         <NA>
2  2000-02-01 -0.50232345   Feb -0.1519638  Jan-Feb-Mar
3  2000-03-01 -0.33320738   Mar -0.6180354  Feb-Mar-Apr
4  2000-04-01 -1.01857538   Apr -0.8078580  Mar-Apr-May
5  2000-05-01 -1.07179123   May -0.5956127  Apr-May-Jun
6  2000-06-01  0.30352864   Jun -0.1066843  May-Jun-Jul
7  2000-07-01  0.44820978   Jul  0.2682475  Jun-Jul-Aug
8  2000-08-01  0.05300423   Aug  0.4744938  Jul-Aug-Sep
9  2000-09-01  0.92226747   Sep  1.0084521  Aug-Sep-Oct
10 2000-10-01  2.05008469   Oct  0.8271070  Sep-Oct-Nov
11 2000-11-01 -0.49103117   Nov -0.2500385  Oct-Nov-Dec
12 2000-12-01 -2.30916888   Dec         NA         <NA>
```

**2) base**  Without packages it will be more complex but you can hide the increased complexity in a function, `roll3`, as shown:

```
roll3 <- function(x, FUN, ...) {
   if (length(x) < 3) {
       rep(NA, length(x)) 
   } else c(NA, apply(embed(x, 3)[, 3:1], 1, FUN, ...), NA)
}

transform(df, moving_x = roll3(x, mean),
              month_window = roll3(as.character(month), paste, collapse = "-"))
```

giving:

```
         Date           x month   moving_x month_window
1  2000-01-01  0.37963948   Jan         NA         <NA>
2  2000-02-01 -0.50232345   Feb -0.1519638  Jan-Feb-Mar
3  2000-03-01 -0.33320738   Mar -0.6180354  Feb-Mar-Apr
4  2000-04-01 -1.01857538   Apr -0.8078580  Mar-Apr-May
5  2000-05-01 -1.07179123   May -0.5956127  Apr-May-Jun
6  2000-06-01  0.30352864   Jun -0.1066843  May-Jun-Jul
7  2000-07-01  0.44820978   Jul  0.2682475  Jun-Jul-Aug
8  2000-08-01  0.05300423   Aug  0.4744938  Jul-Aug-Sep
9  2000-09-01  0.92226747   Sep  1.0084521  Aug-Sep-Oct
10 2000-10-01  2.05008469   Oct  0.8271070  Sep-Oct-Nov
11 2000-11-01 -0.49103117   Nov -0.2500385  Oct-Nov-Dec
12 2000-12-01 -2.30916888   Dec         NA         <NA>
```

Also, note that the question itself uses a package.  The month could be obtained like this:

```
df$month <- format(df$Date, "%b")
```

Comment: This is an amazing solution and I will file this away for future applications. However, I failed to mention (rectified now) that I need a base R solution for this if it is possible.

Comment: Have added base solution.